# How to get two boxplots on same axis?

Tags: python, data-mining, visualization, graphs

I have two dataframes (both of different lengths, etc) but they have exact same columns and I would like to explore the distribution of one of these columns by plotting a boxplot.

However, how do I get it on the same axis? And how can I set the y-axis for this? The below code puts the boxplots side by side in separate graphs but I would like them to have the same axis so I can compare them easier.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.boxplot( x="status",y="assets" ,data=df1, palette="Set3",ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot( x="status",y="assets" ,data=df2, palette="Set3",ax=axes[1])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is how to visualise your box plots so that they appear in the same plot (axes).

To do this, it is simply a minor alteration to your code.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.boxplot(x="status",y="assets" ,data=df1, palette="Set3",ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(x="status",y="assets" ,data=df2, palette="Set3",ax=axes[0])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The alteration is on the `data=df2` line.